# 5V Relay and Arduino to control a 6v nerf gun

Tags: relay, arduino

I am super confused how to hook up this relay
http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2062480

The nerf gun has a  spdt switch for the trigger and runs on 4 AA's .

Comment: Spelling fixed!

Comment: Dupe? http://chiphacker.com/questions/1043/controlling-high-voltage-device-with-arduino

Comment: For that RS price you can have 3 relays at Digikey...

Answer (score 3):

Relax, it will not be that hard. First of all, work out which pins are for the relay's coil. Then, have a look at this article: http://tronixstuff.wordpress.com/2010/04/20/getting-started-with-arduino-chapter-three/  :)

[edit] D'oh - Joby beat me by 10 seconds

Answer (score 2):

You need a transistor to drive the relay from an Arduino pin.

[Here's a tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Expermentation-Kit-How-to-get-Started-wi/step13/Larger-Loads-Relays-CIRC11/) with some Arduino diagrams.

If you're driving a motor, you will need a diode also.

Comment: I HAVE to have a transistor? What type?

Comment: That is a DPDT relay, I am not sure how to hook up a spdt

Comment: Number of poles on the other side shouldn't make the switching any different. You'll just need to identify more pins if there's no data.